# iOS RxSwift - how to use Amb Operator?

Tags: ios, swift3, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm looking for example of Amb() operator for RxSwift.

I have two observables - started and stopped and I want to create code which would execute if one of them emits, while ignoring emissions from the other one.

```
let started = viewModel.networkAPI.filter { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                return true
            case .failure:
                return false
            }
        }

    let stopped = viewModel.networkAPI.filter { result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            return true
        case .failure:
            return false
        }
    }
```

I tried:

```
    Observable<Bool>.amb([started, stopped])
//error - Ambiguous reference to member 'amb'
//Found this candidate (RxSwift.ObservableType)
//Found this candidate (RxSwift.ObservableType)
```

and:

```
 started.amb(stopped)
//error - Generic parameter 'O2' could not be inferred
```

**How do I properly use RxSwift AMB operator to pick one of two observables to emit a value first?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the code you posted. My guess is that your `Result` type is generic and the started and stopped observables are filtering off of different types of Result. In essence, started and stopped have different types and therefore, `amb` won't work with them.

You can test this by doing `let foo = [started, stopped]` and then testing the type of `foo`. You will probably get the error:

> Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

```
//convert both to the same emission type,
//then apply .amb after one of them

let stoppedBoolType = stopped.map { _ -> Bool in
    return false
}
started.map{ _ -> Bool in
    return true
    }.amb(stoppedBoolType)
```

Comment: You are correct, I got confused by .filter and .map - they were split across multiple lines. I needed to .amb the two boolean observables and was trying to do this before their results were mapped